# Are the remaiders $\beta \mathbb{N} - \mathbb{N}$ and $\beta K_0 - K_0$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

Are the remainders $\beta \mathbb{N} - \mathbb{N}$ and $\beta K_0 - K_0$ homeomorphic (where $K_0$ means the Cantor set without a point and $\beta$ means the Stone-Cech compactification)?

Comment: It seems that they're both just a single point, right?

Comment: @SantanaAfton Far from it. $|\beta \mathbb{N} - \mathbb{N}| = 2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under CH (the continuum hypothesis) the answer is yes: theorem 1.2.6.in the [introduction to $\beta \omega$](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.vanmill/papers/papers1984/handbook.pdf)  has the following corollary to Paravicenko's theorem under CH:

> (CH) If $X$ and $Y$ are zero-dimensional, locally compact, non-compact, $\sigma$-compact spaces of weight at most $\mathfrak{c}$, then $\beta X - X$ and $\beta Y - Y$ are homeomorphic.

Note that $\mathbb{N}$ and $K_0$ are such spaces.

Maybe ideas like these work: we can write $K_0 = \cup_n C_n$ all clopen compact and pairwise disjoint, and map $C_n$ to $n$ and extend to $\beta \mathbb{N}$. This maps $\beta K_0 - K_0$ onto $\beta \mathbb{N} - \mathbb{N}$ (by perfectness, e.g.). It this map were 1-1,  we'd have an absolute homeomorphism, not dependent on CH.